# Saving Java applet parameters into session or cookie

Tags: java, session, cookies, applet

I have a simple question, but since I have never worked with applet before I need help: I have a Java applet that requires user to login. After login I would like to save login parameters (uname and pass) to the session or cookie, so next time user starts my applet, login could be automatic.
Is there a way to save / read session and cookie from Java applet and how to do it?

Comment: Well i'm sure that this answer is simple 'cause applets (at least should) have easy mechanism for using cookies...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check This out

http://www.java-gaming.org/index.php?topic=24016.0

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/doingMoreWithRIA/accessingCookies.html

Might be helpful thanks